# What is the equivalent query for 'NOT IN' in Volt DB?

Tags: sql, voltdb

What is the equivalent query for 'NOT IN' in Volt DB?

Comment: I mean function

Comment: refer the synopsis and description  
[HERE](https://docs.voltdb.com/UsingVoltDB/sqlref_select.php)

Comment: Can you show @SharathRavi What you want to achieve ? An example would help, with a scenario even better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VoltDB supports NOT IN syntax:

```
1> create table foo (a integer);
Command succeeded.
2> insert into foo values (1);
(Returned 1 rows in 0.00s)
3> insert into foo values (2);
(Returned 1 rows in 0.00s)
4> insert into foo values (3);
(Returned 1 rows in 0.00s)
5> select * from foo where a not in (1,2);
A
--
 3

(Returned 1 rows in 0.00s)
```